# Java Exception for an integer value in excess of a specified range

Tags: java, exception

I've recently learnt about throwing exceptions in java.

I'm currently working on an exercise to write a method that takes one integer (between 1 and 100) as a parameter, and stores it against an instance variable. If the integer is not within the specified range, an error is reported through an exception.

After much searching over which exception class to use, I believe IllegalArgumentException would be most appropriate in this scenario.

However, with such a high volume of exception classes, is there a suggested methodology to establish which exception class to use?

I am about to sit an exam whereby this sort of question is likely to be raised. I am able to bring in a textbook as reference material, yet time will be limited, and I certainly won't be able to/have time to go through all available exception classes.

Are there more commonly used exception classes that I should always refer to first?

Comment: There is no right/wrong answer of which kind of exception to throw. It all depends on the context. `InputMismatchException` may be another example or you can also create your own custom Exception `NumberNotInRangeException`

Comment: You _could_ just write your own exception (extend from `Exception`).

Comment: The `InputMismatchException` is designed for use by the `Scanner` class and is not appropriate here. And it makes little sense to create a new type of `Exception` unless one of the standard Java API ones really does not fit.

Comment: Thanks both - unfortunately under examination conditions this wouldn't be possible due to time constraints as it wouldn't gain me any additional marks unless specifically requested that I write my own.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your assessment: `IllegalArgumentException` is a perfect fit. The [Java API specification for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) says:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

Which is exactly the scenario you describe.

As for a methodology, there is no hard standard, because there will always be a degree of subjectivity involved in deciding how to interpret the definition in unusual cases. But in the case you describe this sounds fairly clear cut.

However, Java gurus like Joshua Bloch argue that a `RuntimeException` (such as `IllegalArgumentException`) should be used when the contract of a method has been broken. So if you did feel you need to create a new type of `Exception` to handle bad input to a method, it should extend `RuntimeException`. The thinking here is that the programmer has failed to obey the contract of the method, so there is little point in expecting him to catch the exception he created.

Comment: Thanks Arkanon - in this instance I was asked for an exception that dealt with an integer outside of a specified range, but it's likely that there may be other questions for which different exceptions would be more appropriate (e.g. division by zero, inputting a letter for a number, referring to a file that cannot be found). I almost have to second guess what is most likely to come up at a beginner level examination, and then make myself au fait with those. Are there any frequently used exceptions that you would suggest learning?

Comment: Well, you usually don't need to throw `NullPointerException` explicitly at the start of a method since Java 1.7 because it's much easier and tidier to call the [`Objects.requireNonNull(Object, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) method. And `UnsupportedOperationException` is appropriate if a subclass does not support a method defined by its interface or superclass (though this situation should be avoided whenever possible). And `IllegalStateException` is useful if a method is called when an object is not ready for it.